# moving from Hibernate entitymanager 3.6.9 to 4.1.2 crashed mysql connection

Tags: java, hibernate

I realise there are posts on migrating from 3.x to 4.x.

However, I am unable to decipher and correlate what those guides are saying to what I need to do with my maven dependencies or my code.

Specifically the operation failed after

> TypedQuery q = em.createQuery(blah..);

at

> List result = q.getResultList();

When the Driver is attempting to get connection, ending up in croaking

> No suitable driver found ...

I could not find any direct answers as to whether I need to

- make changes to persistence.xml
- make changes to my code
- realign my JPA paradigm

Are there any changes I need to make to my code and my maven dependencies? Should I even bother with getting accustomed to hibernate 4?

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="z666" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>z666.Node</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="zzz" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="666" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/z666" />
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I got the same error for <hibernate.version>4.1.2.Final</hibernate.version>. After a dreadful night, this morning I find 4.1.5.Final is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing the MySQL driver `mysql-connector-java-<version>.jar`  [Current version](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) is `mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar`.  You need a maven dependency like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.20</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't know what versions are acceptable for Hibernate 4 but I think you need at least 5.1

Comment: Not missing but included in maven pom is 5.1.16. Just to remind, using hibernate 3.6.9 with my current maven pom works. So no jars missing.

Comment: @Blessed, "No suitable driver found" means it cannot load the JDBC driver. Either it cannot find the jar or there's something wrong with the JDBC URL.  Your URL looks good, so I suspect it cannot find the jar.  In any case, this is a problem with your build/dev/test/deploy environment but since you've provided no details about that I cannot be of much help.

Comment: Reminder again -- no problem with url because it works with hibernate 3.6.9. Question is not about problem with Hibernate. Question is about what to do to migrate to Hibernate 4. This question must be answered by someone having gone thro the migration to Hibernate 4.

Comment: @Blessed, "No suitable driver found" is not a normal error message to get when migrating to Hibernate 4.  Generally migrating is very easy.

Comment: @Blessed, to be clear, all I did to upgrade to Hibernate 4 was change `<hibernate-core.version>3.6.9.Final</hibernate-core.version>` to `<hibernate-core.version>4.1.2.Final</hibernate-core.version>` in the `<properties>` section of my `pom.xml`.  Note that current version is 4.1.3.Final.