# Is there such a version as JPA 3?

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, jpa, ejb

AFAIK, the latest and greatest that I have been using is JPA 2.0.

I am befuddled that GAE has a jar somewhat called appengine-java-sdk-1.6.5/lib/user/orm/geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar. I have been having the impression that GAE always has a latency in adopting compatibility with latest, greatest bleeding edge protocols. It took them some time to adopt JPA 2.0.

What is that JPA 3.0 jar doing inside GAE SDK libs? Is there such a version as JPA 3.0? Is Google one-upping us this time by implementing a new version protocol ahead of everyone else? Is there a JPA 3.0 spec or reference impl somewhere I could refer to?

I am not (currently) an EJB person (sorry ... had decided to avoid EJB ever since I had bad experience with EJB 1.0 10 years ago).

- Is EJB 3.0 synonymous with JPA 2.0,
- or is JPA 2.0 adopted as a subset of EJB 3.0
- or is JPA 3.0 = EJB 3.0?

WRT this question I asked: [moving from Hibernate entitymanager 3.6.9 to 4.1.2 crashed mysql connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490129/moving-from-hibernate-entitymanager-3-6-9-to-4-1-2-crashed-mysql-connection),
Is Hibernate entity-manager 4.x somehow related to JPA 3.0 or at least a JPA version later than 2.0? I am experiencing significant differences between Hibernate entity-manager 3.x and 4.x (and have so far avoided deploying 4.x).

I realise this question is rather self-confusing and may be I should have asked each of the items as individual question, but I am hoping some one could tie all these together in a single thesis: ejb 3, JPA 2/3, geronimo, hibernate ent-mgr 3/4. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there is not such a thing (in June 2012) as JPA3. There is JPA1, JPA2, and (in planning) JPA2.1. That geronimo-specs jar is actually for JPA1 but some very shortsighted person/group decided to name it like that, and are now seeing the consequences of it.

As you say GAE already does support JPA2, using v2.x of their JPA plugin as available from Maven repositories or here http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/  and that works with a compatible jpa-api v2 jar (such as geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec).

Answer (score 7):

As others have said, JPA 2.0 is the current version (part of Java EE 6) and the next version is going to be JPA 2.1 which is currently in specification ([JSR 338](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338)) and going to be included in Java EE 7. There is no JPA 3 as of yet, so that JAR is just badly named.

JPA 1.0 was introduced as part of Java EE 5, splitting the persistence part from the EJB specification (so Java EE 5 introduced EJB 3.0 and JPA 1.0, no more Entity Beans, yeah!). Java EE 6 then included EJB 3.1 and JPA 2.0.

Java EE 7 will include [EJB 3.2](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=345) and JPA 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

I am speaking under correction here as things might have changed since I last seriously worked with JPA. However JPA 2 from my understanding is the current specification. I doubt the jar you mentioned is a JPA 2 specification. In 2011 Geronimo did not support JPA 2 out of the box at that point.

As far as EJB's and JPA is concerned:

1. Both EJB and JPA are based on POJO's (Plain Old Java Objects).
2. JPA classes is essentially a data access layer technology i.e. used to interact with your data layer.
3. EJB is essentially used for a business layer. It would contain business logic and orchestrate interaction between different JPA classes. For example in JPA you might have a Customer Class (which interacts with the Customer Table) and a Orders Class (which interacts with the Orders table). In your EJB you will use both these classes to create a new order for a particular customer.

When using JPA as a technology it allows you to keep your database access funtionallity in one layer. This layer could be used by EJB's, a web application(Servlets,JSP,JSF), web services and even a swing application. This will keep the database access logic consistent across all these applications. Changes to the database will then require a change to the JPA.

This is a very simplified explanation of the differences and this subject matter is really deep but these points should help you differentiate between the two.

By the way the new EJB specification really makes beans very easy to use, develop and deploy. I am lucky I missed the original specification all those years ago. Currently they are very easy to use.

Hope this helps clear up the mist a bit.